# Strategy to manage and organize Contractor's Work and change requests

Tags: change-management, subcontractor

We have subcontractors doing work for our company, and all of the information is exchanged between e-mails. I found out that every time someone asks for info, we need to look back at our e-mail, then copy-paste the info.

What is not good is that some of the info is outdated, as people may refer to older emails and there are some corrections on later emails. In summary, all the information is scattered in our emails and some of the deliverables are sent via email.

We have JIRA and a git repository but I don't think management will be ready to expose and give access to external subcontractors.

How do you effectively manage the information and change requests for subcontractor work? I am planning to have a centralized system (like a wiki or shared google docs for the information and a version control system for the  deliverables) specifically for outside work from subcontractors wherein the access will be restricted to every subcontractor we are dealing with. But I am not sure if that is the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said you're using JIRA but are leery about giving access to external subcontractors...

For simplicity, I will assume you have only one subcontractor and one JIRA Project; if not, this Answer can be scaled up. I also assume you have a free license to create an account for your subcontractor; if not, depending on your setup, you may be able to use anonymous access instead.

What you may wish to consider is creating a second JIRA Project and then give your subcontractor full read (and possibly write, if you wish) authority *to that Project only*. What you then do is create a filter that includes both Projects (private and public), and then create a board associated with that filter.

This way, internally, you will be able to see all issues (both those created internally and externally) in one place. The subcontractor, however, will only be able to see issues belonging to the public Project. This way, any information you wish to be shared with the subcontractor may be put in the public Project, while any confidential information may be kept private.

You may also wish to configure the board to display to which Project each issue belongs.

Disclaimer: I've only ever used JIRA Agile, but I assume this would work for JIRA Software as well.